# Netsuite advance PDF/HTML template: Setting footer to show only on the last page

Tags: pdf, netsuite, bfo

I'm having a problem making the footer show only on the last page of the PDF. What I am thinking is that I'll get the last page number and display the footer if the `pagenumber == totalpages`.

But I can't get the value of `<pagenumber>` tag and assign it to a freemarker variable because it is a tag in BFO. Is there any way I can accomplish that?

```
<#if pagenumber != totalPage>
  <macro id='footer'>Normal Footer</macro>
<#else>
  <macro id='footer'>last page footer</macro>
</#if>
```

I am a beginner at this.

Answer (score -1):

You just need to specify the footer to use in the ***last***  reference in the template like ***footer="childpagesfooter"***. childpagesfooter points to a macro where you have the HTML for the footer

```
<pbr header=""
         footer="childpagesfooter"
         header-height="0mm"
         footer-height="0mm"
         width='200mm'
         height='500mm'
         size='Letter'/>


// macro example
<macro id="childpagesfooter"><div class="ui-div-footer">My Footer</div></macro>
```

Comment: Tried that one before but the footer is getting repeated in every page, what I need is that the footer needs to be displayed ONLY at the last page. Thanks for trying to help tho. :)

Comment: @ChadricGotis Did you find anything in this? I also need something like this.